# jQ Masonry: isFitWidth vs gutter, or NumberOfCols? How to fill up the whole container

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

masonry.desandro.com Using isFitWidth, i am able to have my elements fill up the container div, but they are all crammed together, no margin/gutter. Using gutter, I am able to specify the margins, correctly, but i am left with whitespace on the right side.

I would like to use some combo of these two or possibly isFitWidth plus be able to spec the number of columns (i dont see a setting for that).

If you could say isFitwidth:true,gutter:50, and have gutter be more of a soft number, to where it would try to use 50, but fudge a little if needed to fill up the width, that would be great.